# How does Bridging a Native UI Component with data work in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

For context, I have bridged parts of a native iOS SDK to React Native already but as I begin to bridge parts of a native Android SDK to React Native I wondered if the community had a better approach.

In order to bridge Native UI Components of an iOS SDK with data, I first used a view manager to export a custom view and multiple properties. Then I bridged a native module containing a couple functions to be invoked by javascript that are responsible for fetching data. After invoking the native module’s functions in javascript, I assigned the data fetched to the custom view’s multiple exported properties.

Is there a way when bridging native UI components (Android or iOS) to bridge a native UI component to javascript that is populated by asynchronously fetched dynamic data?

I made a simple version of the approach I pursued in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/braxtonb/a7f85e92fb981ee6f07f7777aac12ce6)